# Anyway to balance loads in tomcat by partitioning User Names?

Tags: apache, tomcat, hash, load

For example: Once a user logged in, server side then needs to route the http traffics to a certain tomcat instance because all his/her files(not in DBMS but in local HD) stored on that machine and there will be interactions between the web app and underlying FS. Anyway to do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is often done by redirecting to a server specific URL at or following login.  The users session then continues with that URL.  I frequently find www replaced with www1, www2, etc, after login on sites I use.

Comment: Yes,URL rewriting is a solution.